How to force login on wordpress error
I have encountered the error There has been a critical error on this website. on my wordpress site and I don't have FTP logins. How can I force login with the web logins

I don't understand what you're asking. What do you mean force login? Did you just mean fix the site?

The site should have emailed you the error, if you've got emails set up correctly. Else you'll have to talk to your host about getting access to the error logs to see what's gone wrong. And hopefully they'll give you a way to access the filesystem too.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You could disable some plugins through the database, but I assume you don't have access to it?
If you do have access to phpMyAdmin, you could follow these steps to deactivate plugins:

Log in to phpMyAdmin (or similar database management tool).

Select your WordPress database.

Go to the wp_options table.  Find the active_plugins row in the
option_name column.

Edit the option_value of active_plugins.

Copy the content of the field and keep it as a backup, then delete
its content (this will deactivate all plugins).

Check your site: If it works, the issue was with one of the plugins.
You can then log in and activate them one by one to find the
culprit.


